# jquery input text with replace is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm using [jQuery tags input library](https://github.com/xoxco/jQuery-Tags-Input) in my angularJS project. On frontend side, I able to add the tags, but when I retrieve the texts for that input. It contains spaces in between the values. I tried to use replace function on the string variable, it doesn't work.

**HTML**

```
<input id="news_tags" data-js-tags-input="" type="text" name="example-tags1" value="" ng-model="news.tags" 
class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" data-tagsinput-init="true" style="display: none;">

<div id="news_tags_tagsinput" class="tagsinput" style="width: 100%; min-height: 36px; height: 36px;">
  <span class="tag">
    <span>tag1&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
    <a href="#" title="Removing tag">x</a>
  </span>
  <span class="tag">
    <span>tag2&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
    <a href="#" title="Removing tag">x</a>
  </span>
  <div id="news_tags_addTag">
    <input id="news_tags_tag" value="" data-default="Add tag" style="color: rgb(102, 102, 102); width: 68px;">
  </div>
  <div class="tags_clear"></div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
var tags  = jQuery("#news_tags_tagsinput .tag span").text().trim();
alert((typeof tags)); // String
alert(tags.replace(" ", ",")); // tag1 tag2
alert(tags.replace(" ", ",")); // tag1 tag2
alert(tags.replace("&nbsp;", ",")); // tag1 tag2
alert(tags.replace("&nbsp;&nbsp;", ",")); // tag1 tag2
```

**Output**

```
tag1 tag2
```

**Instead Of**

```
tag1,tag2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to pattern split string

```
var tags  = jQuery("#news_tags_tagsinput .tag span").text().trim();

alert(tags.split(/\s+/));
```

the regex means

```
\s = find whitespace character
+ = one or more characters
```

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery plugin handles this for you. Instead of trying to get the tag spans manually, you should simply fetch the value of the underlying input:

```
jQuery("#news_tags").val() //comma-delimited list of tags
```

Comment: This will returns empty in my case because my input value is empty, and the plugin library only insert new div tag class everytime user inserts new tag.

Comment: I looked at the plugin source. There is a function named `updateTagsField` which is called every time the user adds a tag. Even if your input is initialized with an empty value, calling `.val()` on it will return a comma-delimited list of the tags a user has added to it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var tags = jQuery("#news_tags_tagsinput .tag span").slice();
alert(tags[0].textContent.trim() + "," + tags[1].textContent.trim());
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j4d0ko17/

Answer (score 0):

For angular js I recommend us angular library instead jquery. You can try with http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/

```
var tags  = jQuery("#news_tags_tagsinput .tag span").text().trim();
alert((tags.split(/\s+/)).join());
```

Though, I do not recommended split using space as any of tag contains space, will be considered as multiple tag instead single.